# Displaying sections on pdf sidebar with \section*{}

Tags: sectioning, pdf, bookmarks

I want to display a section on the sidebar of the `.pdf`. Unfortunately, it seems that it does not appear when I am using `\section*{section_name}`. But it appears when I use `\section{section_name}`

How to display the section heading on the side bar using `\section*{section_name}`?

Comment: `\section*` does not enter the `ToC` and as such does not enter the `PDF` outline. Please  provide a compilable document. It should be possible with the `\currentpdfbookmark` macro, however. Of course you don't mean `section_name` literally, do you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No section_name is just a dummy. But suppose I want to use \section{name} but wish to hide the section number. Will it then work?

Comment: Yes, but hiding the number is the crusher ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's only one `\section*` like - content to be entered to the `bookmark` (or PDF outline), the easiest way is to strip the number by a quick `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` and later restore it to the old value. This way, the `\section{Foo}` is not numbered, but enters the `ToC` still and has an bookmark entry.

I assumed the `article` class here, which has a `secnumdepth` value of `3` by default.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Foo}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\clearpage
\section{Other section}


\end{document}
```

[image]